# Trabalhando com datas de planilhas

Tags: python, openpyxl

Galera, estou buscando dados em uma planilha utilizando python, e em uma das Worksheets contem somente datas. O problema é que quando eu busco essas datas elas vem em forma de tuplas que são imutáveis. Gostaria de alguma sugestão de como tratar essas datas, pois será necessário comparar elas com outras datas.

```
def fetch_datas(wb):
    temp = []
    dados = list()
    for sheet in wb.sheetnames:
        for row in enumerate(wb[sheet].values):
            if row[0] == 0:
                continue
            temp.append(row)
```

segue o link do arquivo: https://drive.google.com/file/d/13YCxd4w_EaNAQp4DzUWPLfvn7OhYfy0-/view?usp=sharing

Comment: O ideal pra dúvidas que contenham acesso a árquivos é disponibilizar ou o arquivo pra podermos trabalhar em cima dele e te ajudar ou só uma parte do arquivo/exemplo, se simplesmente der um exemplo de tuplas geradas ao ler a worksheet já ajudaria bastante!

Comment: Disponibilizei o arquivo no Google Drive e a parte do código que me retorna a Tupla com os dados.

Answer (score 1):

Dê uma olhada nessa resposta: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13962837/reading-date-as-a-string-not-float-from-excel-using-python-xlrd

Nela, voce encontra essa linha de código que pode te ajudar:

```
a1_as_datetime = datetime.datetime(*xlrd.xldate_as_tuple(cell_value, book.datemode))
```

Fiz um código básico que lê as datas:

```
import xlrd, datetime


def open_file(path):

    book = xlrd.open_workbook(path)
    first_sheet = book.sheet_by_index(0)

    num_rows = first_sheet.nrows - 1
    num_cells = first_sheet.ncols - 1
    curr_row = -1

    while curr_row < num_rows:
        curr_row += 1
        row = first_sheet.row(curr_row)
        print ('Row:', curr_row)
        curr_cell = -1
        while curr_cell < num_cells:
            curr_cell += 1
            cell_type = first_sheet.cell_type(curr_row, curr_cell)
            cell_value = first_sheet.cell_value(curr_row, curr_cell)
            #print (' ', cell_type, ':', cell_value)
            if cell_type == 3:
                a1_as_datetime = datetime.datetime(*xlrd.xldate_as_tuple(cell_value, book.datemode))
                print ('datetime: %s' % a1_as_datetime)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    path = "excel.xlsx"
    open_file(path)
```

Em 'first_sheet.cell_type(curr_row, curr_cell)', voce consegue ver o 'tipo' do dado de cada célula do excel. Para datas, o tipo é "3". Então quando o código encontra uma celula com tipo 3, ele aplica a linha que citei mais acima para dar o cast para datetime.

***Para que isso funcione dessa maneira, voce deve alterar o tipo das celulas do excel para data.***

Você pode ver a lista completa dos tipos em: https://xlrd.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#xlrd.sheet.Cell